# Analog operation for Python code to JavaScript RE Module

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, split, python-re

Here is the code :

```py
        lines = re.split('\\s*\\n+\\s*', text)

        joint_stack = []

        for line in lines:
            words = re.split('\\s+', line)
            instruction = words[0]
```

My JS code is :

```
  _parse_hierarchy(text) {

    var lines = text.split('\\s*\\n+\\s*');

    console.log("Test _parse_hierarchy  -> ", lines);
```

I got array but i got whole text in one item. My array length is 1.

Looks like i need regex to split by line...

I also try `var lines = text.match('\\s*\\n+\\s*');` with no success.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct way for js format: `\\` => `\`
and without `'` or `"` .

```js
    var lines = text.split(/\s*\n+\s*/);

    console.log("Test lines  -> ", lines);

   for (var key in lines) {

      var line = lines[key];
      console.log("Test _parse_hierarchy FIRST WORD  -> ", line);

      var words = line.split(/\s+/);
      // var firstword = words[0];
```